# Delete Item from ListBox with DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource

I have a listbox whose DataSource is a List who contains folders name. I want delete the folders from listbox and the path, but the first it doesn't work.

Here the code:

```
private static List<string> themesF;

 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

 List<string> dirs = new List<string (System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"Thems"));
var pngs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"Thems").Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png"));
            themesF = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Count; i++)
            {
                themesF.Add(dirs[i].Substring(6));
                Console.WriteLine("A) Directorio " + dirs[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("B) Carpeta" + themesF[i]);
            }
            lb.DataSource = themesF;
            pbx.ImageLocation = (@"Thems\" + themesF[0] + @"\Preview.png");

        }
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String folder = lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
        themesF.Remove(folder);
        lb.DataSource = null;
        lb.DataSource = themesF;
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"Thems\" + folder,true);

    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger to tell you why.  Place a stop on the `String folder = lb.SelectedItem.ToString();` line and follow what happens.

Comment: Folder take the value from lb.selecteditem
"folder"

lb.datasource have 17 folder s
before i put value as null
lb.selecteditem is now "";

themesF have 17 folders, exactly as datasource.
With I remove, I have 16 folder, 
lb.Datasource = themesF It have 16 folders.
selected item is now folder1 but is still selected folder

Comment: Use a BindingList instead of a List.  Remove those DataSource lines in the click event.

Comment: Its works! Thank you! How I can you choose you comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` doesn't report changes to the list, so try using a `BindingList<T>` instead:

```
BindingList<string> themesF = new BindingList<string>();
```

Remove those DataSource lines from the Remove_Click event since those won't be necessary anymore.  Just set the DataSource once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folder = themesF.Find(t=> t.Equals(lb.SelectedItem.Text));
    themesF.Remove(folder);
    lb.DataSource = themesF;
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"Thems\" + folder,true);

}
```

When you want to delete something from list, one way is find it first.
And when you write this : lb.DataSource = something; You don't need to put null there first.

Comment: With this, the folder is deleted but this still show in listbox.

Comment: if text in lb.SelectedItem.Text is the your string's text It will delete. Or u can write it this way :     themesF.Remove(themesF.Find(t=> t.Equals(lb.SelectedItem.Text)));    . both are the same

Comment: And it is, but I don't know why this form it doesn't work for me. Anyway, many thanks for the comment.

Comment: Try debuging the code so maybe there is a mistake in there and you could find it. good luck, your welcome.